# npm install supplying custom metadata

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I want to develop a new NPM package, say, `@me/myconfig`, which right after `npm install @me/myconfig` (i.e. at dependencies installation time) would fetch a piece of data from http API and place its home directory as a source code, say, `node_modules/@me/myconfig/config.json`. Assume that the postinstall hook can expose a config in any format from the package [1].

This is done to later require this package in **any kind** of the source code (client or server) and have that piece of config data available synchronously, for example in React:

```
import { config as buildTimeConfig } from "@me/myconfig";
import { FC } from "react";

const Page: FC = () => {
  return <div>
    Here's my config: {JSON.stringify(buildTimeConfig)}
  </div>
};

export default Page;
```

**The question is:**

- *If I want to supply some kind of a parameter to that HTTP API the package requests **at the install time**, what is the way to do it?*
- *Is it possible to do it with just a single `npm install <package>` alone and no extra work? (ask a lib user to set envs or create files before npm install)*

Ideally, I want something like `npm install @me/myconfig@1.0.0#custom-id-here`. The parameter I want is some kind of ID of the config requested through API, for example, `abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop`, so the HTTP request would look like `https://my-api.com/config?id=abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop` and will fetch a specific config.

FAQ

- Why not to request the API at runtime, f.e. with `fetch()`? => because of system architecture considerations, latency etc; the piece of data is constant.
- Why not to copy-paste the config into the source? => it is big and sometimes gets updates. We want a fresh config on each (client, server) build.
- Why not to fetch config manually at build time? => a need to have the simplest possible from the user's PoV solutions (ideally, no-actions-needed), which I see possible with `npm install` as it's ubiquitous.

---

[1] Out of scope of this question.